# I tried to make two interactve buttons. They're interactive, but not buttons

Tags: html, css

**I don't know what part of my CSS is preventing me from making the button after I introduced the pseudo-classes, it went wrong. The purpose is to make a blue button in the center with a 20px margin-top and a blue button under it. They display the colors when you hover over them, but they don't appear permanently**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'/>
    <title>CSS Selectors</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'/>
    <style> 
       .synopsis {
  color: #7E8184;        /* Light gray */
  font-style: italic;
}

.synopsis em {
  font-style: normal;
}

.button:link ,
.button:visited {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #5995DA;    /* Blue */
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #5D6063;    /* Dark gray */
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.button:hover,
.button:visited:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #76AEED;  /* Light blue */
}

.button:active,
.button:visited:active {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #5995DA;  /* Blue */
}



.call-to-action:link,
.call-to-action:visited {
  font-style: italic;
  background-color: #EEB75A;     /* Yellow */
}

.call-to-action:hover,
.call-to-action:visited:hover {
  background-color: #F5CF8E;     /* Light yellow */
}

.call-to-action:active,
.call-to-action:visited:active {
  background-color: #EEB75A;     /* Yellow */
}

.page {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a:link {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: purple;
}
a:hover {
  color: aqua;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
  color: red;
}

a:visited:hover {
  color: orange;
}

a:visited:active {
  color: red;
}

p:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

p:first-of-type {
  color: #7E8184;
  font-style: italic;
}

#button-2 {
  color: #5D6063;  /* Dark gray */
}
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='page'>
    <h1>CSS Selectors</h1> 

    <p class="synopsis">CSS selectors let you <em>select</em> individual HTML elements in an HTML
       document. This is <strong>super</strong> useful.</p>

    <p>Classes are ridiculously important since they allow you to select
       arbitrary boxes in your web pages.</p>

    <p>We’ll also be talking about links in this example, so here’s
       <a href='https://internetingishard.com'>Interneting Is Hard</a> for us to
       style.</p>
    <a href='#button-2'>Go to Button Two</a>
    <div class="button" href='nowhere.html'>Button One</div>
    <div id='button-2' class='button call-to-action' href='nowhere.html'>Button Two</div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like so? You forgot to add a reference to the ".button" class itself with ".button:link, .button:visited". The page did not read any css for ".button" since it wasn't defined so your styling was not displaying

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'/>
    <title>CSS Selectors</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'/>
    <style> 
       .synopsis {
  color: #7E8184;        /* Light gray */
  font-style: italic;
}

.synopsis em {
  font-style: normal;
}

.button,
.button:link ,
.button:visited {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #5995DA;    /* Blue */
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #5D6063;    /* Dark gray */
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.button:hover,
.button:visited:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #76AEED;  /* Light blue */
}

.button:active,
.button:visited:active {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #5995DA;  /* Blue */
}



.call-to-action:link,
.call-to-action:visited {
  font-style: italic;
  background-color: #EEB75A;     /* Yellow */
}

.call-to-action:hover,
.call-to-action:visited:hover {
  background-color: #F5CF8E;     /* Light yellow */
}

.call-to-action:active,
.call-to-action:visited:active {
  background-color: #EEB75A;     /* Yellow */
}

.page {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a:link {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: purple;
}
a:hover {
  color: aqua;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
  color: red;
}

a:visited:hover {
  color: orange;
}

a:visited:active {
  color: red;
}

p:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

p:first-of-type {
  color: #7E8184;
  font-style: italic;
}

#button-2 {
  color: #5D6063;  /* Dark gray */
}
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='page'>
    <h1>CSS Selectors</h1> 

    <p class="synopsis">CSS selectors let you <em>select</em> individual HTML elements in an HTML
       document. This is <strong>super</strong> useful.</p>

    <p>Classes are ridiculously important since they allow you to select
       arbitrary boxes in your web pages.</p>

    <p>We’ll also be talking about links in this example, so here’s
       <a href='https://internetingishard.com'>Interneting Is Hard</a> for us to
       style.</p>
    <a href='#button-2'>Go to Button Two</a>
    <div class="button" href='nowhere.html'>Button One</div>
    <div id='button-2' class='button call-to-action' href='nowhere.html'>Button Two</div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```